# When does a type "circular reference itself"?

Tags: typescript

I don't get why "type circular reference itself" sometimes appears and sometimes don't.

Example:

```
type Item = string;

type CollapsableItem = (Item | CollapsableItem)[];  // Fine

type CollapsableItem = [(Item | CollapsableItem)];  // Fine

type CollapsableItem = [Item, ...(Item | CollapsableItem)];  // TS2456: Type alias 'CollapsableItem' circularly references itself.
```

The only different in the last one is that I enforced the first element in the array to be `Item`. Why did that all of sudden cause a `circular reference type error`?

In general, when does a "type circular references itself" error occur?

Comment: The first variant declares a list of arbitrary length where every element is either a string or a list of the same type. The second variant declares a list of only one element which is either a string or a list of the same type. What do you think that the third variant declares? It's a list where the first element is a string, but what about the rest?

Comment: @md2perpe the rest is of arbitrary length where each remaining element either is of type `Item` or `CollapsableItem`. OH! That's a bummer. All I need is `type CollapsableItem = [Item, ...(Item | CollapsableItem)[]];  // Fine`

Answer (score 1):

Like you mentioned it was just a typo; it should be

```
type CollapsableItem = [Item, ...(Item | CollapsableItem)[]]
```

To add context, using the rest operator `...` on anything other than an array type is invalid typescript and will result in the following.

```
type A = [string]
type B = [...(string | A)]

// Error: A rest element type must be an array type.
```

The reason why the typescript compiler said your code was circular instead of that it used rest on the nonarray type `Item` is a compiler priority decision, and your declaration was invalid for both of those reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I recently got a compilation error TS2456 with the latest npm install about ResultType circularly referencing itself in node_modules@types\arcgis-js-api\index.d.ts

The compile error goes away when I edit this file and replace:

```
   export type ResultType = number | string | Date | boolean | Graphic | Geometry | any | ResultType[];
```

With:

```
    export type ResultType = number | string | Date | boolean | Graphic | Geometry | any | ResultTypeArray; 

    export interface ResultTypeArray extends Array<ResultType> {}
```